# SMS sending: System says SMS delivered successfully, but actually not

Tags: android, sms, send

My app sends SMS via SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage and then notifies the server about the status of SMS sending.

Everything works fine, but there is a problem with Yota operator. SMS is not delivered to phones with MTS operator. Employees of the Yota operator claim that MTS operator blocks receiving messages from Yota.

This is not our problem, but the Android system says that such SMS successfully delivered. We cannot redeliver such SMS from another phone because our system thinks that they have already been successfully delivered.

If app tries to send such SMS, the system first signals about successful SMS sending and then about successful SMS delivery. Sounds good, but in fact the SMS is not delivered. This is not an isolated case. Tested on different devices. Also tried to send SMS to different phones with MTS operator.

I tried to send the same SMS through a standard "Messages" application and noticed the following:

SMS, sent from my application, are displayed differently in a standard "Messages" application on different devices. For example, ZTE BLADE L110 (API 22) shows an error sending a message and Xiaomi Redmi 3S (API 23) does not. But on both smartphones when I try to send such SMS via the standard application is shown error sending message (ZTE before this shows Toast "SMS successfully sent").

Who can help? Can there be another way to check if the SMS is delivered or not? How does the standard "Messages" application register the fact of SMS sending error while the system generates intents with signals that the message was successfully sent and delivered?

Here is my code:

Sending SMS job:

```
public class SendSMSJob extends SimpleJobService {

    public static final String EXTRA_SMS_LIST_JSON = "sms_list";
    public static final String TAG = "send_sms_job";

    private static final String ACTION_SENT = "ru.sp2all.smsgate.SMS_SENT";
    private static final String ACTION_DELIVERED = "ru.sp2all.smsgate.SMS_DELIVERED";

    private int startId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyLog.i(getLogTag(), "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public int onRunJob(JobParameters parameters) {
        try {
            this.startId = startId;
            String json = parameters.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_SMS_LIST_JSON);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            SMSDataList smsDataList = gson.fromJson(json, SMSDataList.class);

            MyLog.d(getLogTag(), "Sending " + String.valueOf(smsDataList.items.length) + " messages");

            boolean complete = true;
            boolean needRetry = true;
            for (SMSData sms: smsDataList.items) {
                Integer subscriptionId = SimsHelper.getSimSubscriptionIdForIndex(getApplicationContext(), sms.simIndex);
                SmsManager smsManager = null;
                if (subscriptionId != null) {
                    smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
                } else {
                    smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                }
                ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(sms.message);
                MyLog.i(getLogTag(), "parts.size=" + parts.size());

                insertSmsToDB(sms, parts);

                ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<>(parts.size());
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<>(parts.size());

                try {
                    for (int part = 0; part < parts.size(); part++) {
                        Intent sentIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SENT);

                        sentIntent.putExtra("id",     sms.smsId + "_" + Integer.toString(part));
                        sentIntent.putExtra("sms_id", sms.smsId);
                        sentIntent.putExtra("parts",  Integer.toString(parts.size()));
                        sentIntent.putExtra("part", Integer.toString(part));
                        sentIntent.putExtra("phone", sms.phone);
                        sentIntent.putExtra("msg", sms.message);

                        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                Integer.parseInt(sms.smsId) * 100 + part,
                                sentIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        sentIntents.add(sentPI);

                        Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(ACTION_DELIVERED);

                        deliveredIntent.putExtra("id",     sms.smsId + "_" + Integer.toString(part));
                        deliveredIntent.putExtra("sms_id", sms.smsId);
                        deliveredIntent.putExtra("parts",  Integer.toString(parts.size()));
                        deliveredIntent.putExtra("part",   Integer.toString(part));
                        deliveredIntent.putExtra("phone", sms.phone);
                        deliveredIntent.putExtra("msg", sms.message);

                        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                Integer.parseInt(sms.smsId) * 100 + part,
                                deliveredIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
                    }

                    MyLog.i(getLogTag(), "Sending to " + sms.phone);
                    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(sms.phone, null, parts,
                            sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ErrorReporter.exception(this, getLogTag(), e, new ErrorReporter.ReporterHandler(e));
                    complete = true;
                }
            }
            if (complete) {
                return RESULT_SUCCESS;
            } else if (needRetry) {
                return RESULT_FAIL_RETRY;
            } else {
                return RESULT_FAIL_NORETRY;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorReporter.exception(this, getLogTag(), e, new ErrorReporter.ReporterHandler(e));
            return RESULT_FAIL_RETRY;
        }
    }

    private String getLogTag() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Registered in AndroidManifest Broadcast receivers for SMS status handling:

```
    <receiver android:name=".SMSSentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ru.sp2all.smsgate.SMS_SENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".SMSDeliveredReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ru.sp2all.smsgate.SMS_DELIVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

SMS sent BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SMSSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String sms_id = intent.getStringExtra("sms_id");
            int part = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("part"));
            MyLog.d(getLogTag(), "br_sent " + sms_id);

            int status = 0;

            int code = getResultCode();

            switch (code) {
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    status = 400;
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    status = 401;
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    status = 402;
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    status = 403;
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    updateDBWithNewSentPartsCount();
                    status = 202; // 202 is SMS sent Server status
                    break;
                default:
                    status = 404; break;
            }

            if (status == 202) {
                int sent = getSentPartsFromDB();
                int parts = getAllPartsFromDB();
                MyLog.d(getLogTag(), "DB sent:" + sms_id + " - : sent:" + sent + " parts: " + parts);
                if (sent >= parts) {
                    MyLog.d(getLogTag(), "DB sent all parts");
                    Network.sendSMSStatus(context, sms_id, status);
                }
            } else {
                Network.sendSMSStatus(context, sms_id, status);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorReporter.exception(context, getLogTag(), e, new ErrorReporter.ReporterHandler(e));
        }
    }

    private String getLogTag() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

}
```

SMS delivered Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class SMSDeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String sms_id = intent.getStringExtra("sms_id");
            int part = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("part"));
            MyLog.d(getLogTag(), "br_delivered " + sms_id);
            int resultCode = getResultCode();

            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    updateDBWithNewDeliveredPartsCount();

                    int delivered = getDeliveredPartsFromDB();
                    int parts = getAllPartsFromDB();
                    MyLog.i(getLogTag(), "DB delivered: " + sms_id + ", " + delivered + " parts of " + parts);
                    if (delivered >= parts) {
                        MyLog.i(getLogTag(), "DB delivered all parts");
                        Network.sendSMSStatus(context, sms_id, 200); // 200 is SMS delivered Server status
                    }

                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    MyLog.w(getLogTag(), "DB delivered: CANCELLED " + sms_id);
                    Network.sendSMSStatus(context, sms_id, 405);
                    break;
                default:
                    MyLog.w(getLogTag(), "DB delivered: unknown code " + resultCode);
                    Network.sendSMSStatus(context, sms_id, resultCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorReporter.exception(context, getLogTag(), e, new ErrorReporter.ReporterHandler(e));
        }
    }

    private String getLogTag() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Log from device when I try to send SMS and SMS not delivered actually:

```
SendSMSJob: onCreate()
SendSMSJob: Sending 1 messages
SendSMSJob: parts.size=1
SendSMSJob: Sending to +7988*******
SMSSentReceiver: br_sent 704402
SMSSentReceiver: DB sent:704402 - : sent:1 parts: 1
SMSSentReceiver: DB sent all parts
Network: sendSMSStatus status: 202
Network: get: https://{SERVER_NAME}/result.php?status=202&smsId=704402
Network: got: {"status":200}
SMSDeliveredReceiver: br_delivered 704402
SMSDeliveredReceiver: DB delivered: 704402, 1 parts of 1
SMSDeliveredReceiver: DB delivered all parts
Network: sendSMSStatus status: 200
Network: get: https://{SERVER_NAME}/result.php?status=200&smsId=704402
Network: got: {"status":200}
```

Text of SMS for test: gate4

Answer (score 0):

SMS is not an acknowledged protocol. You can't know if it has been delivered from the sending end. The sender can only know when the message is sent. The send is reporting correctly, as the data is being sent, but it is being blocked at the other end.

If you need acknowledged SMS you can reply from the receiver, but this will involve developing you own acknowledging protocol.

I'd just poll a web service from the device. Data is a *LOT* cheaper than SMS messages anyway.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. But how standard "Messages" application register sms sending error?

Comment: If the "Messages" application reports a sending error, then there is actually an issue uploading the message. It isn't like sending a TCP message. It is closer to sending a mail (not email as some servers will actually report failure to send).

Comment: If the "Messages" application reports a sending error, then there is actually an issue uploading the message. I understand that, but it happens always. Result of Sending SMS via my app and standard "Messages" app is the same: SMS is not delivered. But standard application recognize that fact. My app does not, because system says that message successfully delivered.

Comment: SMS are not delivered because MTS blocks receiving from Yota. There is no reason to think that there is a difference in the cause of undeliverable messages when sent from my application and from the standard.

Comment: So if you send exactly the same message using "Messages" or your application it returns a different result? That is odd. Can this program send to a non-MTS phone/modem without issues?

Comment: So your phone and the modem you are sending with programmatically are both on the Yota network, trying to send to the MTS network and one reports failure and the other does not?

Comment: is the phone supplied by Yota? Maybe they have some additional logic in their version of "messages" which does a lookup of the number.

Comment: Yes, It can. It sends SMS to non-MTS phones correctly. I tested it few seconds ago. This application is used by us to send verification codes to users of our system for 4 years. We faced different problems, but if the SMS was not delivered, the system always notified the error.

Comment: Is the program doing the sending using an actual SMS modem or is it using a web SMS gateway? This would make it a different scenario to the phone reporting an error.